# MSVS. How do I tell NUnit to use /noshadow parameter when tests are executed?

Tags: visual-studio, nunit

I would like to send /noshadow parameter to nunit when I run my tests from MSVS.

Basically I run tests by right mouse click on test icons located left to source code window.

[image]

I don't know how to configure parameters that are sent to nunit then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using Resharper, to change the noshadow setting you open the Resharper -> Options... menu and go to the Tools -> Unit Testing panel.

There is a "no shadow" option to Control the shadow copying behaviour:
[image]